# How to make a images Directory in Jboss Server Standalone folder at the time of deploying the war file in jboss server?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, web.xml

Without Request from Client to Server.I want to Create a Folder in JBoss Standalone Folder.

First Thing i want to know is it possible for creating a folder in jboss at deployment time.

If it is Possible then Any body can tell How many way are present to create a folder at deployment time.

Thanks in Advance.